# Python to JavaScript for iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, python, mobile, pyjamas

Have a webapplication with backend developed on python ( running on Django) and front end on HTML5 & javascript. Python generated data is passed on to JavaScript/HTML using JSON.

Now, I would like to make it a mobile application, iPhone app to begin with. 
The Front end is very much the same with changes in CSS files to make it look like iPhone native application ( Thanks to jQTouch )

What options do  I have to make the back end Native on iPhone/ other Mobiles?

I'm not sure how stable and easy pyObjc / [cobbal](https://github.com/cobbal) is. Secondly my belief is, using these solutions makes it not so portable to other Mobiles.

So was thinking of converting python code to Javascript and running it all inside browser. I believe pyjamas/ [py2Js](http://www.mccarroll.net/py2js/) will do good job of conversion.  Has anyone done this ? are there any flaws in this design ? Any better options avaliable ?

Best, 
Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I cannot understand is why you need your backend being native to iPhone. This doesn't make sense. The backend is a server-side infrastructure that speaks HTTP, so it is independent from your frontend, which may be implemented in any language (usually in HTML/Javascript, but also a GUI in *).

Then, there is [coffeescript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/). It's a scripting language that compiles to javascript, and it feels like python/ruby, so it is easy to write javascript code in a more pythonic way.

Comment: The application needs to be native for complete offline working. I woudn't like make any access to server, unless there are loopholes in deisgn.   I liked coffeescript ... although simple, needs coding in yet another language.